# Cannot Resolve Symbol Context

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to Android development and I just saw a video showing how to add a slider to android. This issue I am facing with is of `context` `(Cannot Resolve Symbol Context)`. On all the 3 spots it's showing red.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewFlipper v_flipper;

    int[] imageos={

            R.drawable.slider,
            R.drawable.slider,
            R.drawable.slider,
            R.drawable.slider,
            R.drawable.slider,

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        v_flipper=findViewById(R.id.v_flipper);

        for (int i=0;i<imageos.length;i++){
            flip_image(imageos[i]);
        }

    }

    private void flip_image(int i) {

        ImageView view=new ImageView(context:this);
        view.setBackgroundResource(i);
        v_flipper.addView(view);
        v_flipper.setFlipInterval(4000);
        v_flipper.setAutoStart(true);

        v_flipper.setInAnimation(context: this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        v_flipper.setOutAnimation(context: this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines to:

```
ImageView view=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
v_flipper.setInAnimation(getApplicationContext(),android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
v_flipper.setOutAnimation(getApplicationContext(),android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

If it is an activity you can use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: I tried error is gone however app crashes when I run it?

Answer (score 0):

on your class define Context first

```
ViewFlipper v_flipper;
    Context context;

int[] imageos={

        R.drawable.slider,
        R.drawable.slider,
        R.drawable.slider,
        R.drawable.slider,
        R.drawable.slider,

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    v_flipper=findViewById(R.id.v_flipper);
context=this;
    for (int i=0;i<imageos.length;i++){
        flip_image(imageos[i]);
    }

}

private void flip_image(int i) {

    ImageView view=new ImageView(context);
    view.setBackgroundResource(i);
    v_flipper.addView(view);
    v_flipper.setFlipInterval(4000);
    v_flipper.setAutoStart(true);

    v_flipper.setInAnimation(context,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    v_flipper.setOutAnimation(context,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
}
```

Comment: Now Context is considered however ':' is being shown as error

Comment: remove : no need for it you can set context directly like this     ImageView view=new ImageView(context);

Comment: did initialized context inside on Create   context=this;?

Comment: I do not understand that part can you please explain how I can do it?

Comment: share full activity code, i will add this on your code.

Comment: check my answer again please check onCreateView method.

Comment: I copied it as you shared above but app crashed

Comment: what is the crash details.

Comment: <viewFliper
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/v_flipper"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    </viewFliper>

Comment: It's nothing it just crashes